# How to run a query with multiple condition in mysql?

Tags: mysqli

code:

```
SELECT * FROM `detail` WHERE country='Malaysia' or state='' or region='' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4
```

In this query I want to find record which is related to `malaysia`. Only one record that I have in my table which is related to `country='malaysia'` but it show other `4` records. I don't have any idea why its happening?. So, How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are also including records which have empty string for the state or region.  Maybe you should just be checking the country field:

```
SELECT *
FROM detail
WHERE country = 'Malaysia'
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove

```
ORDER BY rand()
```

because sql doesn't sort the result by default, so this statement is superfluous.